# How to print certain lines of an input text file to another file in VB

Tags: vb.net, file, text, input

I have a large file which i am writing to a smaller file in VB, i just dont know how to select lines from an input file that i opened.

I would like to keep the first 12 lines of the large file and them copy every 3rd line into the new output.
Any help?!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a `StreamReader` - just open one on the file, then you can call `ReadLine()` on it as many times as you need.

Easiest implementation would probably be a 0-to-11 (or 1-to-12) `For` loop, then a `While` where you read 2 and ignore them, then read the 3rd and write it.

Writing the new file can be done with `StreamWriter`, which just has a `WriteLine()` method to write the text.

The `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` are generally the easiest ways to read and write text files.